# bitmap recycle(); shows error and the image is not displayed

Tags: android

i tried the recycle method in my code but it seems that its not working properly.i have a viewpager in the start of my app and it has got around 5 images in it and i have used bitmap recycle to recycle it

```
        Bitmap tempImage = ImageSampleManager.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),tutorial_images[position], 240, 240);
        view.setImageBitmap(tempImage);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        tempImage.recycle();
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: `its not working properly` - probably the most useless statement in programming.  *Exactly* what error do you get, when do you get it and please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: No no n. You can not recycle a Bitmap while you are using it. recycle frees the bitmap from the memory

Comment: Maybe you call tempImage.recycle() too early: the image is still used by the view so trying to recycle it will fail. Try to call it in onDestroy() if possible. Also, will be nice to show us some logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid creating a stackoverflow topic and waiting for an answer by reading the documentation.
`Bitmap.recycle()` is used to notify the system that you are no longer using this bitmap and that it can be freed from the memory.
So of course you can't display it if you recycle it first.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check:

```
   Bitmap tempImage;
   if (tempImage != null && !tempImage .isRecycled()) {
                tempImage = null;
   }
    tempImage = ImageSampleManager.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),tutorial_images[position], 240, 240);
    view.setImageBitmap(tempImage);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
   // tempImage.recycle();
    return view;
```

Comment: so hat should i do actually